# Confused about iPad Serial Numbers and Generation - Help Needed!

Tags: ipad, settings, serial-number

Hello Apple community,

I recently purchased an old Apple iPad (5th generation - 2017) from a marketplace, and I noticed something peculiar about its serial numbers. On the back cover, the serial number reads "DMPTL3GRHP9X." However, upon checking the serial number inside the iPad (in the Settings), it displays a different one: "DMPJJ6K8F186." Additionally, when I used the Apple website to verify the serial number, it showed that the iPad belongs to the "iPad 4e génération - 2012." This discrepancy has left me quite confused about the actual generation of my iPad.

My concern is whether the iPad has been tampered with or if there is any possibility that components from a 4th generation iPad were replaced with 5th generation components, even though it shows the 5th generation in the "About" section in Settings.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue with their iPads? Can someone from the community or an expert shed some light on this matter? I want to make sure I have an authentic 5th generation iPad, and any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On the back cover, the serial number reads "DMPTL3GRHP9X." However, upon checking the serial number inside the iPad (in the Settings), it displays a different one: "DMPJJ6K8F186." Additionally, when I used the Apple website to verify the serial number, it showed that the iPad belongs to the "iPad 4e génération - 2012."

You have a very good reason to be concerned.

When the SN# in firmware doesn’t match what’s etched on the cover, you can be certain that the logic board was replaced. The fact that the firmware SN# indicates a previous generation iPad means you didn’t get what you paid for.

This appears to have been assembled with various components. Even if all other components are gen 5, the most critical component, the logic board is gen 4.  Bottom line: it’s a gen 4.

Return it to the seller as “not as described/advertised.”

Comment: Thank you for your input! I appreciate your help in clarifying this. Your insights have been invaluable. Thanks again!

Comment: I just hope you can get a satisfactory resolution from the seller.  It genuinely bothers me that people do this to others

Comment: The ipad 4 has an A6X cpu vs an A9 in the 5th gen, which is about 50% faster. So it's indeed an inferior ipad to what was advertised.